# Can Mystery Gift send more than one item at a time?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-bank

Can I receive more that one item via [Mystery Gift](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mystery_Gift)?

I've just updated the Pokebank to get the [Mewnium Z](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/mewniumz.shtml), and Brigette suggested me that I have earned a lot of Pokemiles (which can be turned into BPs).

So here's the question: can I send the Mewnium Z and the BPs together via Mystery Gift? Or does the second item overwrite the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple Mystery Gifts waiting for you in Sun and Moon. From the [Serebii page on Mystery Gifts](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/mysterygift.shtml):

> When using separate software such as the Pokémon Sun & Moon Special Demo Version or Pokémon Bank, **when the software is going to send special Pokémon or items to the game, it will do it by automatically adding the Wonder Card to your save file.**

And then further down on the page:

> The cards are stored in the Card Album and **you can hold up to 48 different Wonder Cards at any one time**.

If you have multiple gifts waiting to be picked up, you can even pick them all up at once (assuming you have space in your party, depending on what the gifts are).

> From Sun & Moon, if you have multiple distributions waiting to be picked up, **you can accept the option to pick them all up simultaneously.** This is very useful with items. For Pokémon, you do need a slot in your party and Synchronise will not work to change the nature of the gift.

Comment: Ok, thank you, the part I need is just the last one. Seems plausible, Munchlax and its Z Crystal come as separate gifts but they can be redeemed simultaneously.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in sun and moon, if you don't have space in your party, the pokemon will just be sent to your box instead.